# Failed to start the kernel on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I have python versions `3.6.5_1` and `3.7.0`installed via Homebrew.
`jupyter` needs python`3.6` for launching. It wouldn't start if I switch to python`3.7`.

After launching, it fails to start the kernel with this error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7': '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'
```

From what I understand, the kernel is looking for python`3.7`. My kernel list has just python3

```
$jupyter kernelspec list  
Available kernels:  
python3    /usr/local/etc/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I looked at [this link on github](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270), but it wasn't helpful. How do I make jupyter and the kernel running on the same python version?

Comment: to install a kernel on jupyter `python3.7 -m ipykernel install`. Are you sure that all your python3 are install with homebrew ?

Comment: @Erwan, yes all my python3 is installed via Homebrew

Comment: Check is jupyter installed for python 3.7 via `help("modules")` in python 3.7 console

Comment: @Alex, I do not see jupyter in the list of modules.

Comment: @nac001 Use `pip3 install jupyter` to install it. (You need to use `pip` of python 3.7)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check the kernel specifications:

```
$jupyter kernelspec list
```

This will show you the available kernels. In this case:

```
python3    /usr/local/etc/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Open the `kernel.json` file in this directory and specify the path of python you want the kernel to use in the `argv` key.

Comment: I am facing the same error , I have run the following command you mentioned in the question and that return me   `python3    C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\iris_1\share\jupyter\kernels\python3` . Now next i am not understand how can i specify the path of python..

Comment: @AhmedYasin, there's a `kernel.json` file in the path you mentioned. You have to change the kernel path there.

Comment: Thanks for this. My `kernel.json` had a path to the python executable in an env, and not the system wide one. This solved it.

Comment: I ran "which python3" and updated argv with the same path and that fixed my issue. Thank you !

Answer (score 11):

Updating the jupyter notebook resolved the issue for me.
But remember, update it using command line. Not Anaconda Navigator

```
pip install -U jupyter
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone anyone reading this who runs Jupyter Notebook from within Anaconda and gets the same error:

I found a workaround by installing Jupyter using pip in the command prompt (not anaconda prompt):

```
$pip install jupyter
```

and then start Jupyter using the known way

```
$cd 'DirectoryofyourNotebook'
$jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

step 2 command:

```
conda activate <location of your env folder>
```

step 3 command:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

works!

Comment: Please provide a full process as it doesn't include step 1. An explanation as to how this works will further help the OP as well.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience.. step 1 would be starting the terminal...  Actually I found this solution from "https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/kernel-error-in-jupyter-notebook-fail-to-start/2260/5" by Claudio_pena and thought it would be helpful for others..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue - tried all the above without success.

Context: using Windows on that machine, for a few years. I have used this machine as a "code on the go when I need to" laptop and have not been very careful nor consistent when installing/upgrading python versions or libraries or environments.

The fix for me -  **somehow a folder that contained f2py.exe (Numpy - on top of which Pandas is built) was not in the path** and was in a hidden folder that ended with "\Scripts". **Python itself was fine** in the environment variables. They were in very different folders - while normally they should be in close branches in the folder tree. Adding the full path of the folder ending with "\Scripts" that have f2py.exe in the environment variables solved the kernel issue for me.

Comment: I assume readers are comfortable with path and env variables. If not check the official doc or the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh winsock reset
```

In cmd with administrator, Please implement above order

Comment: netsh winsock reset