# Jupyter Notebook : Could not find a kernel matching python 3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried installing jupyter notebook without using anaconda and ran into some issues, specifically the red 'Kernel Error' that kept showing up.

However through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934528/failed-to-start-the-kernel-on-jupyter-notebook) ques I was somewhat able to identify the issue where the default pythonpath in the `kernel.json` file in `C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3` was for anaconda, so I added my python path using `where python`.

On running `jupyter notebook` on cmd and opening a .ipynb file causes a popup to show : `Could not find a kernel matching Python 3. Please select a kernel`, which shows an empty drop down list.

**My Updated kernel.json file:**

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, on running `jupyter kernelspec list` showed an error:

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 3 column 6 (char 18)`

Fixed it by using `C:\\Users\\Ashish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe` in the `kernel.json` file